# (EF) Update related data on insert new entity

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, ado.net

I have `Posts` and `Comments` tables, `Comments` are related to `Posts` by `postId`,
and I need to change `DateUpdated` field in `Posts` table when inserting new `Comment` entity.

Is there any way to do this with one query and how to do it properly if it is not?

Now I`m doing this way:

```
context.Comments.Add(comment);
context.SaveChanges();

context.Posts
.Single(p => p.Comments.Contains(c => comment.Id)
.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select `Post`
2. Add new `Comment` in Post's `Comments` collection
3. Change date
4. Save Changes. EF will generate two statements: insert and update

Like this:

```
var post = context.Posts.FirstOrDefault(...);
post.Comments.Add(comment);
post.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
context.SaveChanges();
```